# addOnScrollListener(RecyclerView) is not working in TabLayout(Fragments)

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I am Developing a app where I have 4 tabs and a recyclerview in each tab.I am able to get the data from web service and add it to recyclerview but, my problem is, I have total 500+ records but, I am getting 50 records each time .I am using EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener to add the data to recyclerview by this example

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/endless-recyclerview-onscrolllistener.html

I am able to add the new data to my recyclerview in activity but i am unable to add in tabs(fragments) even addscrollListener is not triggering and I have another problem when i swipe all the 4 tabs and when I return to first tab old data lost new data is added.

Can any help me where i am wrong ?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.newslist,container,false);

    dateValue=getArguments().getString("date");
    connection = 
    NetworkCheck.getConnectivityStatusString(getActivity());
    appPreferences = new AppPreferences(getActivity());
    newsList= new ArrayList<Model>();
    checkTextView=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.check);
    mRecyclerView =      
   (RecyclerView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    //mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(newsList,getActivity());
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    new GetNewsAsyncTask().execute();
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    thread.start();

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            Log.v("Load more", "Load more");
            loadMoreData(current_page);
        }
    });

    if (!connection.equals("No Internet Connection")) {
        Log.v("List","List"+newsList.size());
    } 
    else {
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        checkTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkTextView.setText("Please check Internet Connectivity");
    }
    return rootview;

}
public void loadMoreData(int current_page)
{
    new GetNewsAsyncTask().execute();
    ival=ival+10;
}
public class GetNewsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>  
 {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        if(ival==0)
        {
            ival = 0;
        }
    }   
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            postText();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {
        // do stuff after posting data

        //  progressDialog.dismiss();
        if(newsList.size()>0){
            checkTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if(adpaValue==0){
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                adpaValue=1;
            }else
            {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        mAdapter.add(model);
                        Log.v("position ", " position runnable " + 
                              newsList.contains(model.getLink()));

                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.v("List","List else");
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            checkTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            checkTextView.setText("No news found");
        }
    }

    // this will post our text data
    public void postText() {
        try {
            // url where the data will be posted
            String postReceiverUrl=                          Constants.newsUrl+appPreferences.getCountry()+"&category=general&skip="+ival+"&next=30&postdate="+dateValue;
            Log.v("TAG", "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);
            String response = 
            GetwebServiceDatanew.getWebServiceData(postReceiverUrl);
            Log.v("response", "response" + response);

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for(int s=0;s<jsonArray.length();s++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(s);
                    model = new Model();
                    model.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                    model.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                    model.setLink(jsonObject.getString("link"));
                    newsList.add(model);
                    Log.v("result","result"+jsonObject.getString("link"));
                    Log.v("result","result"+newsList.size());
                }
                ival=ival+10;
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my code for first tab i have same code for all tabs.

Comment: why have you used `adpaValue` in your code?

Comment: first time i am using setadapter and from second time i am adding the values to recyclerview using  mAdapter.add(model); because when i get new data recyclerview is showing data from first listitem instead of showing from new added data

Comment: I am guessing that your arrayadapter was initialised on empty newList and this adapter was given to the recyclerview. Try adding adapter.notifyDataSetChanged after recyclerview.setAdapter.

Comment: no it is not working addOnScrollListener is not triggering first to add data

Comment: I want some clarification on the question . Let's say you have 4 tabs 1,2,3,4 and initially when you viewpager starts, Is tab 1's recyclerview empty? and when you swipe tab from 1-4 and back from 4-1, tab 1's recyclerview has new data but not old data? When you swipe tab from 1-2, Is tab 2's recyclerview empty? Which fragment viewpager adapter are you using? are you sure that you are getting data from server?

Comment: yes i am getting data when i open first tab but when i scroll down i am unable to fetch new data addscroll is not triggering.but when move from1-4 i am getting new data wher my old data is lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94150/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-fabin-paul).